# Azure Machine Learning

Tags: azure, machine-learning

I can create a machine learning workspace in azure, because I cant choose a region.
Can you help me please?

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yK4WU.png)

Answer (score 2):

Error in the screenshot is quite clear. Essentially your Azure Administrator has set a policy that would disallow deployment of Machine Learning resources in `UK South` location.

You can try to create the resource in some other location which is allowed by the policy or ask your Azure Administrator to disable the location constraint in the policy.

Comment: Hello Gaurav,  Thanks a lot for your answer.  But whatever region I choose it doesn't work, You think that Azure administrator can be reached?  Thanks for the info again.

Comment: That’s correct.